# Get id from parameters from url using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have a url...

```
/pensieve/q/22749623
```

I want to strip this url of everything but the tailing id and store it in a variable...

```
22749623
```

I am able to do this using a simple for loop...

```
var query_id = ''
for(var index = 12; index < query_url.length; index++){
    query_id += query_url[index];
}
var query_id = parseInt(query_id);
```

How do I do this with Javascript using regex?

I am finding a lot about how to do this in other languages, but not Javascript. I have checked StackOverflow and the rest of the internet to no avail.

Comment: if you want to learn how to do it and do it yourself, try this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp. Skål

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this.
(please see [this](https://regex101.com/r/sD9lI1/1))

```js
var link="/pensieve/q/22749623";
var number = link.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/)[1];
console.log(number);
```